# Upgraded Geoserver - How to "reset" / start over with Geowebcache as it is throwing exceptions

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

So I upgraded Geoserver 2.9 running in Jetty on Windows to Geoserver 2.14 running under Tomcat.  I stopped the old, set the GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR parameter in Web.xml in the WEB-INF folder to the location used by Geoserver 2.9.

All is working great except for Geowebcache.  When I select "Tile Layers" under "Tile Caching" in the UI, I get an exception.

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Error attaching this container for rendering: [OddEvenItem [Component id = 4]]
...
Caused by:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.StyleParameterFilter.setLayer(StyleParameterFilter.java:188)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.TileLayerInfoUtil.checkAutomaticStyles(TileLayerInfoUtil.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.TileLayerInfoUtil.checkAutomaticStyles(TileLayerInfoUtil.java:140)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getPublishedInfo(GeoServerTileLayer.java:345)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getLayerInfo(GeoServerTileLayer.java:326)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.web.GWCIconFactory.getSpecificLayerIcon(GWCIconFactory.java:54)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.web.layer.CachedLayerProvider$1.getPropertyValue(CachedLayerProvider.java:43)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.web.layer.CachedLayerProvider$1.getPropertyValue(CachedLayerProvider.java:37)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.web.layer.CachedLayersPage$1.getComponentForProperty(CachedLayersPage.java:86)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$5.populateItem(GeoServerTablePanel.java:238)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.onPopulate(ListView.java:523)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onBeforeRender(AbstractRepeater.java:124)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:950)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1018)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1836)
    ... 144 more
```

If anyone knows where to look to diagnose this, that would be great.

There is not much in the cache at this point in time, so I'd be happy with instructions on how to "start over" with the caching of layers.  Is this a straightforward thing to do?

Can I "clear" the GWC folder somehow, restart Geoserver, and manually turn caching back on for each layer that should be cached?

Comment: Did you ever work this one out? My server has just started doing the same message.

Comment: I think I found in a trace message somewhere that the cache location was not set to where it used to be, and was being defaulted to C:\Temp or something like this.  And the files were not located there so it crashed. I think I rebuilt a new cache from scratch, after ensuring the settings pointed to where I wanted it stored.